# JSON object inconsistent property type

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, reduce

ex 1:

```js
data =`{"serialNo": "1","items":{"item":[{"RECORDNO": "2", "amount" = 40},{"RECORDNO": "3","amount" = 40}]},}`
```

ex 2:

```js
data=`{"serialNo": "2","items":{"item":{"RECORDNO": "4841","amount" = 40}}}`
```

The above is an example of a JSON value returned from an API call. The type is a little inconsistent as seen above.
If the item has only one record,  the json type is an object. If the item has multiple records the json type is an array.
I am interested in extracting the item and process it.

```js
const vals = [data.items.item][0];
vals.forEach(val => {
  // do something
});
```

The code above works well for ex 1 but fails for ex2 as it's not of the type array.
What would be an easiest way to extract the item as an array to process easily.

Comment: That ain't JSON

Comment: `"amount" = 40` isn't JSON. Ditto for the dangling comma. Please show your actual response and how you're parsing this into `data`.

Comment: This is typical of APIs that support both XML and JSON where XML is the primary result type and the JSON is just hacked together from that

Answer (score -1):

Just check whether the property is an array with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray):

```js
const data={serialNo:"1",items:{item:[{RECORDNO:"2",amount:40},{RECORDNO:"3",amount:40}]}};

const data2={serialNo:"2",items:{item:{RECORDNO:"4841",amount:40}}};

function process(res){
  const { item }  = res.items;
  if(Array.isArray(item)){
    console.log(item.map(JSON.stringify))
  } else {
    console.log(item)
  }
}

process(data)
process(data2)
```